# Tkinter - Dynamic Font Size Changing

Tags: python, fonts, tkinter, python-3.5

I have pretty much tried everything, and looked everywhere for how to dynamically change fonts in a `Text()` widget. I don't want all the text in the `Text()` widget to change just the text which is typed after the change of font size, like pages or word etc.

This is what I imagined would work:

```
#in the __init__ function
    sizesList = [8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 22, 26, 32, 40]
    var = IntVar()
    var.set(13)
    self.fontsizeDropDown = OptionMenu(self.toolbarFrame, var, *sizesList, command=self.fontSizeFunc)
    self.fontsizeDropDown.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

def fontSizeFunc(self, var):
    theFont = "Arial %d" % var
    self.textentry.tag_add('texthere', INSERT, INSERT)
    self.textentry.tag_config('texthere', font=theFont)
```

However all it does is change the size of the letter after the cursor, only if there is a letter there, then any further typing goes back to original font size.

Comment: Try changing the second INSERT to END, so you are typing within the configured tag.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I'd tried that too, the cursor size changes, and stays at specified font size, however the typed text remains the default size. Then when i move the cursor in the middle of some text and change the font size, the text from the cursor to the end of the text is changed to the specified size.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Figured out another way to do it, that I liked better so putting this on top with the old one below as reference.

**NEW VERSION:**

The code needs to keep track of where a tag index starts and ends. It will also an unique tag name for each font size. I figured a good tag name could be the same as the font and size used for the tag configuration.

When a new font size is chosen, the text written will get a tag with a starting and ending index, configured with the proper font size. It will then set the new font size, set that to the Text Widget and update variables. The tag will not be added until you change the font size again. But since the Text Widget has the current chosen font size, it will appear with the right size.

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def main():
    def current_index():
        # Return current cursor position in the text widget
        return textentry.index(tk.INSERT)

    def fontSizeFunc(*new_var):
        # Set the tag for the text that has been written
        textentry.tag_add(current_tag.get(), start_index.get(), current_index())
        textentry.tag_config(current_tag.get(), font=current_tag.get())

        # Sets new Font Size, store start_index position for new tag,
        # create a new tag that has theFont as tag name
        theFont = "Arial %d" % new_var
        textentry.configure(font=theFont)
        start_index.set(current_index())
        current_tag.set(theFont)

    # Simple Tkinter setup for testing purpose
    root = tk.Tk()

    sizesList = [8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 22, 26, 32, 40]
    var = tk.IntVar()
    var.set(13)

    frame = ttk.Frame(root)
    frame.grid(column=0, row=0)
    fontsizeDropDown = tk.OptionMenu(frame, var, *sizesList, command=fontSizeFunc)
    fontsizeDropDown.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N)
    textentry = tk.Text(frame)
    textentry.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

    # Initialize start_index and current_tag
    start_index = tk.StringVar()
    current_tag = tk.StringVar()
    start_index.set(current_index())
    current_tag.set("Arial %d" % var.get())

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

If you want to store the text in the Text Widget, remember to set the tag by calling fontSizeFunc() before exiting/storing. Or the last entered text will be without a tag.

**OLD VERSION:**

I was thinking that if you want to have dynamic change, you will have to check the Text Widget for changes. And every time you change font size with the Option Menu, you create a new tag.

In my example code below, it checks for KeyRelease when the Text Widget is in focus. The current tag index will then be expanded as you type, and when you select a new font size it will create a new tag. Used your code where I could, just adjusted it to work without being in a class.

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def main():
    def text_changes(*event):
        # On every KeyRelease with the Text widget in focus,
        # it get the current tag, start index and current index.
        theFont = "Arial %d" % var.get()
        textentry.tag_add(current_tag.get(), start_index.get(), current_index())
        textentry.tag_config(current_tag.get(), font=theFont)

    def current_index():
        # Return current cursor position in the text widget
        return textentry.index(tk.INSERT)

    def fontSizeFunc(*new_var):
        # Create a new tag with a new start index / position
        start_index.set(current_index())
        current_tag.set(current_index())

    # Simple Tkinter setup for testing purpose
    root = tk.Tk()

    sizesList = [8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 22, 26, 32, 40]
    var = tk.IntVar()
    var.set(13)

    frame = ttk.Frame(root)
    frame.grid(column=0, row=0)
    fontsizeDropDown = tk.OptionMenu(frame, var, *sizesList, command=fontSizeFunc)
    fontsizeDropDown.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N)
    textentry = tk.Text(frame)
    textentry.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

    # Initialize start_index and current_tag
    start_index = tk.StringVar()
    current_tag = tk.StringVar()
    start_index.set(current_index())
    current_tag.set(current_index())

    # When the text entry has focus, every key release will run the
    # text_changes function
    textentry.bind('<KeyRelease>', text_changes)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Hope you can use this to build your own better version :)